# Use different OpenSSL Versions dynamically in Single application based on some flag

Tags: c++, openssl

Need to compile one application with 2 versions of OpenSSL shared library/DLL. Version 1.0.2 and version 1.1.1. Version 1.1.1 does not support FIPS. So to support federal customers, We want to continue using 1.0.2 version. For non-FIPS customers, want to use version 1.1.1 which will have many security fixes.

So there will be many APIs added, removed or signature changed. There will be many structures, enums added/removed, or modified. To deal with APIs, we are planning to dynamically load libraries using LoadLibrary/dlopen based on the FIPS flag and call functions through function pointers got using GetProcAddress/dlsym.

Trouble is with structures/enums/defines. To use them, we have to include header files. Header files of both the versions will have the same name, some common declarations. So we can not include 2 such header files in a single CPP file.

We tried with namespaces but it didn't help much. Any suggestions to solve this problem in C++ through some design pattern or through other way will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you design two adapter shims between your application and the different OpenSSL versions to provide a uniform interface to the application and a OpenSSL version-specific interface on the OpenSSL side.The shims should be independent .dll/.so files. Then load the shim you want based on demand. Yes, I know it's easier said than done, but it will isolate the rest of the application from the details of each OpenSSL implementation.

Comment: It will make my code less maintainable for future OpenSSL upgrades. OpenSSL upgrade is frequent activity and such a design will make life more complicated for future upgrades.

Comment: Actually, with the scheme I described, you only need to update the adapter (a standalone, separate dll/so build), or if changes are too many, refactor or rewrite it. The application will not be affected as long as the application-side adapter interface remains the same. This will also let you mock OpenSSL for testing relatively easily with a test adapter.